# How can I fix dimension error while trying to compute and plot Fourier coefficients

Tags: python, fft

I am trying to compute and plot Fourier coefficients for some signal and I am getting the following error:

> ```
> x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1000,) and (1,)
> ```

using the following code:

```
x=np.linspace(0,6, 1000)
y=np.cos(x**2)

#Areglo de 0 a 2pi con la cantida p k=n

def fourier(y):
    for k in range (0,3):
        for t in range(0, n - 1):         
            X = np.sum(y*np.exp(-2j*np.pi*t*(k/n))) 
        return X

a=fourier(y)

plt.plot(x,a)
```

How can I fix that error?

Comment: Sorry, what's your question? also as a note, next time post your code and highlight the code and hit `ctrl` + `k`

Comment: What are you trying to do in your code? What is `n`? Also you are computing `X` within a for loop. It will be returned for k = 0, 1, 2 but since you are overwriting variable `a`, `a` will only contain value for `k = 2`.

Comment: I have to do a function that solve the Fourier transform,  but python report me this problem "x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1000,) and (1,)". Thanks for help

Answer (score 3):

The error

> ```
> x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1000,) and (1,)
> ```

arises as you are trying to plot the results with `plt.plot(x, a)`. In your specific case  `x` is an array of 1000 values, while `a` is a scalar. Your intention was probably to get array rather than a scalar, so let's dive into your `fourier` implementation.

It looks like you are trying to compute the first few coefficients of a [Discrete Fourier Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform). To do so, you need to assign the different coefficients to different indices in the result array `X`. Also the sum should be carried out over the entire vector expression `y*np.exp(-2j*np.pi*t*(k/n))`. By running a loop over the different values of `t`, you would be computing the sum of the elements of `y` scaled by some factor (a different factor for each value of `t`, but the same factor applied to the entire array `y` for each different value of `t`).

Putting this all together you should get the following implementation:

```
def fourier(y, kmax):
    n = len(y)
    X = np.zeros(kmax, dtype=np.complex)
    for k in range (0,kmax):
        t = np.arange(0, n)         
        X[k] = np.sum(y*np.exp(-2j*np.pi*t*(k/n))) 
    return X

kmax = 3
a=fourier(y,kmax)
```

To plot the results, you have to use the same number of points along the x-axis than along the y-axis. Since we computed `kmax` coefficients, we should also limit the number of x-axis point to `kmax`. Finally, since those coefficients are complex numbers you will have to reduce the results to a set a real-valued numbers before plotting. A common application is to get the magnitude of the coefficients with `np.abs`.

```
plt.plot(x[0:kmax],np.abs(a))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do not use scipy fft package? You can plot phase and amplitude spectrum separately. below is an example

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import fftpack

x=np.linspace(0,6, 1000)
y=np.cos(x**2)

best_len = fftpack.helper.next_fast_len(len(y))
yf = fftpack.fft(y, best_len)
xf = fftpack.fftfreq(best_len, np.diff(x)[0])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12, 6))

ax[0].plot(xf[0:best_len//2], 2.0/best_len*np.abs(yf[0:best_len//2]))
ax[1].plot(xf[0:best_len//2], 2.0/best_len*np.angle(yf[0:best_len//2]))


ax[0].set_title('Amplitude spcetrum')
ax[1].set_title('Phase spcetrum')

plt.show()
```

[image]